# Proving $a^n + b$ is divisible by $c$ inductively

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understand the idea generally but I get confused by the presence of the $b$ term.
Can anyone solve this example for me: **prove $6^{2n} + 4$ is divisible by $5$ by induction**

Comment: If you mean $6^{2n}+4$ then that is equal to $(6^2)^n+4=36^n+4$. Are you also confused about how to deal with the $+4$?

Comment: and indeed $6^{2n}+4=(7 \times 5+1)^n+4$ which is going to be divisible by $5$ but will be $2$ less than a multiple of $7$

Answer (score 2):

Show by induction $6^{2n} +4 $ divisible by $5.$

Check : $n=1$ , is ok (so is n=0).

Hypothesis: $6^{2n} +4$ is divisible by $5$.

Step: $n+1;$

$6^{2n+2}+ 4 = 6^{2n} 6^2 +4 =$

$ (6^{2n} +4 -4)6^2 +4=$

$(6^{2n}+4)6^2 -4(6^2) +4=$

$ (6^{2n} +4)6^2 -4(6^2-1)=$

$(6^{2n}+4)6^2 - 4(35);$

The first term is divisible by $5$, hypothesis, the second term $-4(35)$ is divisible by $5 $,

hence the sum of the $2$ terms is divisible by $5$, I.e.

$6^{2(n+1)} +4$ is divisible by $5.$

Answer (score 0):

You can view the equivalence as the following congruence $$6^{2n}+4\equiv 0\pmod 5$$
$$6^{2n}\equiv -4 \pmod 5$$
$$6^{2n}\equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
$$1^{2n}\equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
Now if you want it’s easy to use induction to prove it, but basically it’s true $\forall n$

Answer (score 0):

Since 6 is 1 modulo 5, actually it is obvious. But you can use induction as follows:

For the case n = 1, you have $$6^{2}+4 = 40$$ so the argument holds. Then suppose $$n \ge 2$$ and the argument holds for all n. Then you have $$6^{2n}+4 \equiv 0 (mod 5)$$ by inductive argument. Then we need to prove it for n+1. If we add and subtract 140, we have $$6^{2(n+1)}+4 = 36.6^{2n}+4 = 36(6^{2n}+4)-140$$ Now, by inductive argument $$36(6^{2n}+4) \equiv 0(mod 5)$$ and obviously, $$-140 \equiv 0(mod 5)$$ so it holds for n+1. Then by principle of induction, the argument holds for all n. But you don't really need induction for this case I think.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show $36^n + 4$ is divisible for $5$ for all $n \geq 0$.

The **base case** is $n=0$, for which we see $36^0 + 4 = 1+ 4 =5$.

For the **inductive step**, we assume $36^k +4$ is divisible by $5$ for $k < n$.

We then manipulate the expression $36^n + 4$ as follows:

$$36^n + 4 = 36 \cdot 36^{n-1} + 4 = 36 \cdot(36^{n-1} + 4 - 4) + 4 = 36 \cdot (36^{n-1} + 4) - 140$$

By the inductive hypothesis, $5$ divides and $36^{n-1} + 4$, and it's clear that $5$ divides $140$, so we see that $5$ divides $36^n + 4$

For a problem of the form:  **prove $c$ divides $a^n + b$** the trick will be to write

$$a^n + b = a (a^{n-1} + b) - ab + b$$

Hence **the proof boils down to checking a base case and then that $c$ divides $ab - b$**

In fact the converse follows immediately too: we just showed that $c$ divides $a^n + b$ for all $n \geq N$ if and only if $c$ divides $a^N +b$ and $c$ divides $ab - b$

Answer (score 0):

$6^{2n} + 4$ is divisible by $5$.

So $6^{2(n+1)} + 4 = 6^{2n}*6^2 + 4=35*6^{2n} + (6^{2n} + 4)$ is divisible by $5$.

Or

$6^{2n} + 4 = 5k$.

$6^{2(n+1)} + 4 = 6^{2n}*6^2 + 4 = (5k -4)*36 + 4 = 180k - 36*4 +4 = 180k - 140 = 5(36k - 28)$